# Higher derivatives of weighted zeta function and continuation to $s=1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, analytic-continuation

> Is it possible to analytically continue to weighted reciprocal zeta function $\frac{1}{\zeta_{a}(s)}$ to the point $s=1$ by bounding the quantity
> \begin{equation}
> \left|\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\prod_{k\in S}\left(1-\frac{1}{k^x}\right)\right|\tag{1}
> \end{equation}
> for real $x>1$ and sets $S$ containinnng real numbers greater or equal to $2$?

Here the reciprocal weighted zeta function is defined by

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\zeta_{a}(s)}=\mathbb{E}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left[a_n\prod_{p|n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^{s-1}}\right)\right]
\end{equation}

where $a=\{a_1,a_2,a_3...\}$ is a bounded sequence of real numbers. The motivation behind this definition is that using standard methods one can show that for any complex $s$ with $\Re(s)>1$

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}=\mathbb{E}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left[\prod_{p|n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^{s-1}}\right)\right]\tag{2}
\end{equation}

and so by weighting (2) according to some set $a$ we obtain our definition.

I wish to show that $\frac{1}{\zeta_{a}(s)}$ has an analytic continuation to $s=1$, and to do this we can construct the power series of $\frac{1}{\zeta_{a}(s)}$ about $s=1+\epsilon$ some small $\epsilon>0$ and show that the radius of convergence of this power series is greater than $\epsilon$, thus granting a continuation. To construct this power series we see that

\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{d^n}{ds^n}\frac{1}{\zeta_{a}(s)}\right|&=\left|\frac{d^n}{ds^n}\mathbb{E}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left[a_n\prod_{p|n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^{s-1}}\right)\right]\right|\\
&\leq\mathbb{E}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left[\left|a_n\frac{d^n}{ds^n}\prod_{p|n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^{s-1}}\right)\right|\right]\\
&\leq M\mathbb{E}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left[\left|\frac{d^n}{ds^n}\prod_{p|n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^{s-1}}\right)\right|\right]
\end{align*}

where $M=\sup|a|$. I imagine that (1) has nice bounds, from which we could show that our power series has a suitable radius of convergence thus granting a solution. Is this possible?

EDIT: Motivation for analysis of the weighted zeta function

One can relatively easily show that

\begin{equation}\frac{1}{\zeta_a(s)}=\sum_{q=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(q)\mathbb{E}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[a_{qn}]}{q^s}\tag{3}\end{equation}

If $\frac{1}{\zeta_a(s)}$ has an analytic continuation to $s=1$ and if

\begin{equation}\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{q=1}^N \mu(q)\mathbb{E}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[a_{qn}]\tag{4}\end{equation}

then that is sufficient to show that (3) converges at $s=1$, ensuring the identity

$$\sum_{q=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(q)\mathbb{E}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[a_{qn}]}{q}=0$$

for any bounded sequence $a_n$ for any bounded sequence $a_n$. I have ideas on how to show that (4) holds, and so if one could resolve the question of analytic continuation to $s=1$ I would have this nice identity. For specific sequences $a_n$ one gets various interesting results, like for $a_n$ periodic mod $r$ where we get that

$$\sum_{q=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(q)f(\gcd(r,q))}{q}=0$$

for $a_n$ multiplicative we can show that if $f(n)$ is a multiplicative funnction with $\mathbb{E}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[f(n)]\neq0$ then

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)f(n)}{n}=0$$

having a nice identity to tie all these results together would be the dream and it would be nice if we could establish a large chunk of the criterion by resolving this problem.